# Excel Solver Not Providing Consistent Results

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

I'm trying to use solver to solve a non-linear problem, but the results are not consistent and change under certain conditions.  This problem does not exist when using Risk Solver Platform, but does when using the regular Excel Solver.  The optimization and constraints are not complex, so I don't understand what is going on.

Here is the file: [temp.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pf7tqo6icgg5et6/temp.xlsm?dl=0)

Notice there are macros involved with buttons attached to run the solver.

To Replicate problem:

- Open file
- Click `Months` tab
- Initial Infestation should be at 11%
- Click `Optimize Net Revenue` (Correct Optimal Condition; this is fine)
- Change Initial Infestation to 1%
- Click `Optimize Net Revenue`
- Change Initial Infestation back to 11%
- Click `Optimize Net Revenue`

Note: Optimal Net Revenue is now lower and in the last month the last column is negative when it should be zero.  It seems like solver needs to be reset everytime, or there is a bug, but I can't figure it out.  Here's the macro:

```
Sub Monthly_Solver()

    Application.Run "SolverReset"
    Application.Run "SolverOk", "$T$18", 1, "0", "$F$6:$F$17,$N$6:$N$17", 1, "GRG Nonlinear"
    Application.Run "SolverAdd", "$F$6:$F$17", 5, "binary"
    Application.Run "SolverAdd", "$N$6:$N$17", 1, "$M$6:$M$17"
    Application.Run "SolverAdd", "$N$6:$N$17", 3, "0"
    Application.Run "SolverAdd", "$T$18", 3, "0"
    Application.Run "SolverSolve", True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRG Nonlinear does not guarantee finding the global optimal solution. It finds a local optimal solution and the quality of that solution is affected by the initial values you supply to the algorithm. From Frontline's [website](http://www.solver.com/excel-solver-grg-nonlinear-solving-method-stopping-conditions):

> When the message “Solver found a solution” appears, it means that the GRG method has found a locally optimal solution – there is no other set of values for the decision variables close to the current values that yields a better value for the objective function.  Figuratively, this means that Solver has found a “peak” (if maximizing) or “valley” (if minimizing) – but if the model is non-convex, there may be other taller peaks or deeper valleys far away from the current solution.  Mathematically, this message means that the Karush - Kuhn - Tucker (KKT) conditions for local optimality have been satisfied (to within a certain tolerance, related to the Precision setting in the Solver Options dialog).

Right now, your `Harvest` column has 3131 in `N14:N16`. If you change `initial infestation` to 1% and solve again, `N14:N17` will have the value of 3131. So your initial solution has changed. If you change it back to 11% without changing the value in `N17` the solver may found another local optimal solution. If you set `N17=0` you will get the same solution as the first one.

On a different note, if the only reason for GRG Nonlinear is the binary `Spray` variable and the if/then conditions it represents, you can use linear constraints (so global optimality is more likely).  Here's a [quick reference](http://www.yzuda.org/Useful_Links/optimization/if-then-else-02.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I tried changing `N17=0` to get the same solution, but it doesn't appear to work.  Also, thanks for the reference, but I'm not sure how to define the if/then condition as a linear constraint.

Comment: Here are the steps I follow: The current optimal net revenue in your workbook is 1,661.56. Initial infestation 11%->1% the formula is recalculated and the optimal net revenue is 11,167.71. Optimize net revenue and the solution is 15,416.39. Now, I change N17 to 0, the optimal net revenue is recalculated as 11,292.04. Changing the initial infestation to 11% gives 1,236.14 and clicking on "optimize net revenue" gives 1,661.56 which is the same as the first solution. Is there any step different?

Comment: Ok, yes that is right now.  Now changing the cell above it `N16=0` produces another optimal net revenue that is lower than just having `N17=0` which makes no sense.  I understand that there can local optimal solution, but the solver should be changing the binary variable `Spray` which by changing `F16=1` would produce a larger solution.  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Would it be better to program this as a linear solution?  Thus given a global max?  Is it possible to explain how to program these binary to if/then conditions?  The reference you provided was a bit vague

Comment: Normally, yeah, it makes sense to model it linearly whenever possible because they are solved much more easily. However, I didn't see the multiplication in column `O` and thought the nonlinearity was about the spray variable. You are multiplying two decision variables on that column and I am not sure if you can linearize that. You can try OR-Exchange https://www.or-exchange.org/ It is the SO of these kind of modeling problems.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Yes, I think this is very much a nonlinear problem as it is setup.  And interesting problem with using Excel Solver--as I mentioned in the question--is that Risk Solver Platform does not cause any problems and the solution is as suggested.  It's only when using Excel Solver that this problem comes up.  Do you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: Excel's built-in solver is very limited even for linear problems. Although it finds the optimal solution for reasonable size problems, it might take quite some time. Risk Solver probably has a better solver that can escape from a local optimum (to a better local optimum - again not necessarily to a global optimum). Unfortunately, good solvers are generally quite expensive.

Comment: Thanks for your quick responses and help.  I'd prefer to hand code this in R and may end up doing so to work around this.  Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome though I wasn't able to be very helpful. I hope you can find an easy solution.