# Excel Solver in VBA gives different results than executing Solver manually

Tags: excel, vba, solver

I don't know if this is because of GRG Nonlinear algorithm as 'ayhan' points out  here: [Excel Solver Not Providing Consistent Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35784170/excel-solver-not-providing-consistent-results?newreg=cc0be87a40b74d4a9625cee693162d9f)

But when I execute Solver from a macro with following code:

```
SolverReset
SolverOk SetCell:="$F$5", _
         MaxMinVal:=3, _
         ValueOf:=valor, _
         ByChange:="$D$2", _
         EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
SolverSolve userFinish:=True
```

I don't get the same results as when it is executed in manual

[image: Difference]

I know that the difference is pretty small. Is this normal?

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing that some settings you have set in solver regarding accuracy or upper/lower bound is different from the default settings used in VBA

Comment: Were the start values exactly the same? Solver uses a numerical iteration based method so it might come up with different results if start parameters are different. • Idea: Try to record a macro while doing it manually to see if that makes a difference to your code.

Comment: As both of you have said start parameters were different. Adding that to the code and now it works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The start values for the Solver must be exactly the same for both methods, because the Solver is not using a exact mathematical method, but a numerical iteration based method to find a solution. So it might come up with different results if start parameters are different.